# Flash player crash in browsers in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, adobe-flash

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. I tried Firefox 3.6.10 and Chrome 10.0.648.133. In both the browsers, I am able to view flash videos in Youtube and Facebook. But when I switch to full-screen, the flash player plugin crashes.

Is there a way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely hard to tell you without having knowledge of your upgrade path, the version of Flash, and/or your video card and drivers. That being said, you may want to check out these links:
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35593

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593363&page=4

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1678932

I found this on the Ubuntu forum that you can try:

```
sudo su
mkdir /etc/adobe
echo \"OverrideGPUValidation = 1\" >> /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
```

If none of these work for you at all, consider reporting a bug to Adobe: http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/

You may also want to submit a bug report (if there isn't one already) to the Ubuntu Devs:
https://launchpad.net/bugs